# Regex to match latex command inside another command only at level 1

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a way to match a `LaTeX` command by regexp (I use `perl` to do the substitutions mostly) and surround it by curly braces and, on the other hand, remove them?

The `LaTeX` command can be any part of text has a structure: it starts with backslash `\` followed by the command name optionally followed by brackets optionally followed by any number of pairs of curly braces within which one can have any other latex commands:

```
\com1[options]{ something possibly with \othercommand{ that } can also have arbitrary number of curly braces }
```

Ultimately, I only want to do this to all commands that are at first level (inside another command). But I am able to do it only for the outer commands:

```
(?<=[^{])(\\(?:com1)(?:\[[^[]]*\])?(\{((?>[^{}]|(?2))*)\})*)
```

seems to work well to match any zero level and then simply `{$1}` achieves the effect eg:

```
\com1[opts]{ some \qtyrange{100}{200}{\celsius} and }{something else \gls{abc} $1=1$ not \colortext{\red}{\underline{text}}}
```

to

```
{\com1[opts]{ some \qtyrange{100}{200}{\celsius} and }{something else \gls{abc} $1=1$ not \colortext{\red}{\underline{text}}}}
```

and to go back:

```
\{(\\(?:com1)(?:\[[^[]]*\])?(\{((?>[^{}]|(?2))*)\})*)\}
```

replaced by `$1` does the job. However, when the commands are inside another command, things become elusive with balancing the parentheses. Basically, I want

```
\rpl{text}{ some\com1[opts]{ some \qtyrange{100}{200}{\celsius} and }{something else \gls{abc} $1=1$ not \colortext{\red}{\underline{text}}} but this is already braced {\qtyrange{100}{200}{\celsius}}}
```

should result into

```
\rpl{text}{ some {\com1[opts]{ some \qtyrange{100}{200}{\celsius} and }{something else \gls{abc} $1=1$ not \colortext{\red}{\underline{text}}}} but this is already braced {\qtyrange{100}{200}{\celsius}}}
```

and also be able to remove the braces from the last example to get:

```
\rpl{text}{ some \com1[opts]{ some \qtyrange{100}{200}{\celsius} and }{something else \gls{abc} $1=1$ not \colortext{\red}{\underline{text}}} but this is already braced \qtyrange{100}{200}{\celsius}}
```

I played with `lookbehind` but as I cannot use quantifiers in it, I am not sure how to deal with this problem.

Comment: For balancing parentheses, I'd use a recursive subpattern ([perlre](https://perldoc.pl/perlre)).

Comment: _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think_ “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  _Now they have two problems."_  -- [Jamie Zawinski]

Comment: You've been posting a number of questions about manipulating latex with regular expressions. A different approach might work better.... a quick search on CPAN found [`LaTeX::TOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::TOM) which might be worth looking into. There may be other options too.

Comment: @Shawn That would be a great tool only if it actually worked. It is a mess, does not recognize commands with more than one parameters or beginning of a document. But a tool like this would solve all the problems.

Answer (score -1):

How about this? (https://regex101.com/r/oBT25u/latest)

```
(?<prefix>{[^\\}]++)(?<first_lvl_command>\\\w+(?:\[[^]]++]?({(?:[^{}]+|(?3))*+}))({(?:[^{}]+|(?3))*+})?)(?<closing_bracket>})
```

prefix group captures everything up until the first nested command.
first level command captures optional `[...]` and twice `{...}` with possibly nested parenthesis using recursion.

---

Cannot edit your post because it effects less than 6 characters, but you are missing a closing `}` in the end of your main command.